# Find files whose basenames are the same, but their ext names are not

Tags: filenames

In a directory, how can we find all the files whose base names are the same, but their extension names are not? E.g. `0001.jpg` and `0001.png` and `0001.tiff`, and `0002.jpg` and `0002.png`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want all the unique filenames, here you go:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\([^.]*\).*/\1/' | uniq
```

If you want the files such that more than one of those has the same basename, then use:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\([^.]*\).*/\1/' | uniq -c | sort -n | egrep -v "^ *\<1\>"
```

For filenames with multiple periods, use the following:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' | uniq -c | sort -n | egrep -v "^ *\<1\>"
```

Comment: Thanks @jimmij.  I have just added a third solution to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

A solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (I avoid parsing `ls` output, it's not designed for this task and can cause bugs):

```
perl -E '
    while (<*>){
        ($full, $short) = (m/^((.*?)\..*)$/);
        next unless $short;
        push @{ $h->{$short} }, $full;
    }
    for $key (keys %$h) {
        say join " ", @{ $h->{$key} } if @{ $h->{$key} } > 1;
    }
' /home/sputnick
```

replace `/home/sputnick` by `.` or any directory you'd like ;)

Comment: Might as well use `for (glob("*")) { ... }` in that case, no?

Comment: Yes grawity, I rewrote the code with `glob`

Comment: @sputnick good plan, parsing `printf *` suffers from at least one of the problems that parsing `ls` does.

Comment: @mr.spuratic: Well, `printf '%s\0' *` is fine, and there's a very small chance that even `'%s\n'` would break (I mean, who _uses_ newlines in file names?) But it's still unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Since the only answers here either use `sed` or `perl` and regular expressions, I thought I'd be different and post something debatably simpler.

```
for file in /path/to/your/files/*; do echo ${file%%.*}; done | uniq -d
```

In this example, `${file%%.*}` matches the file path up to the first period (`.`). So, `0001.tar.gz` would be treated as `0001`.

The output would look like this

```
/path/to/your/files/0001
/path/to/your/files/0002
```

If you don't want the full path in the output, simply `cd` into the directory first and then run the command with just a asterisk (`*`) for the path.

```
cd /path/to/your/files
for file in *; do echo ${file%%.*}; done | uniq -d
```

Then the output would look like this

```
0001
0002
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GNU environment, here's a *robust* solution which prints out the common base names, using `gawk` (just to mix it up):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\0" | 
  gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} {sub(/\.[^.]+$/,""); if (length($0))printf("%s\0",$0)}' | 
  sort -z | uniq -zd | 
  tr '\000' '\n'
```

This uses `find` with \0 (nul) delimited filenames, `gawk` with `RS` (record separator) set to \0 to match the input, and a `sub(/regex/)` to strip an extension.

The final `tr` command undoes the nul delimiting for printing to the screen, *omit this for further (safe) processing of filenames*.

(Normally I would do something like `whatever | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | sort`, but `rev` doesn't do nul-delimited input.)

If you want to limit it to only files with a `.ext` or more specific pattern you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" -printf "%f\0" | ...
```

The first option above  only prints the common base, if you want to print out the actual filenames:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" -printf "%f\0" |        
  gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="\0" } 
             { base=$0;sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",base);seen[base][FNR]=$0} 
        END  { for (bb in seen) 
                 if (length(seen[bb])>1) 
                    for (ff in seen[bb]) printf("%s\0",seen[bb][ff])
              }' |    
  tr '\000' '\n'
```

(gawk v4.0 minimum required for multi-dimensional arrays!)

This uses an array (hash) `seen[]` to cache seen file names keyed by the base name, then at the end it iterates over the the base names in `seen[bb]` and prints out those with more than match (`length(seen[bb])>1`).

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't afraid to parse `ls`:

```
/bin/ls --color=no -1 | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | uniq -d
```

That will fail if the file names contain new lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'|uniq -cd
```

awk prints the first field(`$1`) of each files with `.` field separator.

`uniq -d` gives only the duplicates lines, and with `-c` option print the number of occurrences.

```
$ ls -1
 0001.jpg
 0001.tar.gz 
 0001.tiff
 0002.png
 0002.tar.bz2
 001.zip
```

```
$ ls -1 | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'|uniq -cd
 3 0001
 2 0002
```