# Unzipped/zipped file search

Tags: scripting, find, zip, duplicate-files

How am I able to search for duplicate files that are zipped and unzipped, with the same name?

I understand I can do the initial search with the below however, not sure how to pipe in some duplicate file terms...

```
find / -iname \*.zip
```

Comment: check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167874/find-files-whose-basenames-are-the-same-but-their-ext-names-are-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to find all `.zip` files in or below the current directory and check whether there's something with the same name but without the `.zip` filename suffix:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.zip' -exec sh -c '
    for a do
        n="${a%.zip}"
        [ -e "$n" ] && printf "%s\n" "$n"
    done' sh {} +
```

With a directory containing

```
file
file.zip
file2.zip
file3
file3.zip
```

the above command would output

```
./file
./file3
```

This is done by looking for all `.zip` files, and for all found files run a short shell script that strips the extension off each name in turn and checks whether that new name exists or not.

Alternatively, an slightly shorter,

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -exec sh -c '[ -e "${0%.zip}" ]' {} ';' -print
```

This also uses a helper shell script, but it's just testing for the existence of the filename without the `.zip` suffix. If a suffix-less name exists, the zip file's pathname is outputted.

Also possibly relevant:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)